# Segfault when storing reg to var in section .DATA

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm, sections

So I am trying to write some code using x86 and I can't seem to get it to move contents of a register to a spot in memory.

The code is just this

```
global  main

SECTION .DATA
  var_i: DD  0

SECTION .TEXT
    main:
      push  DWORD 4
      pop   EAX
      mov   [var_i], EAX

    mov   EAX,  0
    ret
```

I am using nasm and gcc on the code.
The problem I am having is that whenever I try to move to the spot in memory it segfaults

Comment: Why do you `push` and `pop` to load `eax`? Try this: `mov eax,4` instead.

Comment: The use of the push and pop to load into eax is due this being part of a compiler and the string template for evaluating a sub expression may trample the registries with the value of their evaluation this is actually just the compiled form of
int i = 4;
The segfault still happens if I load 4 into EAX using move though

Comment: You are going to trash the REGISTER (not registry) EAX anyway.

Comment: I understand that. The problem is that if you have something like `int i = ( 5 + (7 * 8));` this is turned into an ast of the form `^(= (VAR_DECL int i) ^(+ 5 ^(* 7 8)))`. The compiler that is being built is not allowed to have any optimization so when this is output as string templates it recurses throught the ast expression evaluating from the bottom up

Comment: You question asks why it seg faults, I am trying to help you simplify the code so you can find the problem. Does the code you show ACTUALLY crash?

Comment: I realize now my previous comment makes it look like I am trying to be snide or something I want to start by saying sorry for that. As for simplifying the code I took you suggestion one step further and removed EAX entirely. Now the body of main is only `mov DWORD [var_i], 4` It still crashes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of system/object format are you using?  I'm guessing you're using ELF on Linux or Unix, as that would explain your problem:

Section names in ELF are case sensitive, and most ELF-based OS's the special sections `.text` and `.data` are understood, but your sections `.TEXT` and `.DATA` have no meaning.  As a result, they just get stuck into the executable after the other sections and get the same access permissions.  If you're just linking the above code, that will be after the `.fini` section, so it will executable and read-only.  So when you try to write to the variable, you get a segfault.

Change your code to use `.data` and `.text` as section names and it should work.

Comment: Thank you this was the problem.